# How do I migrate system folder and app settings to new QNAP volume?

Tags: backup, raid, qnap

I currently have a RAID5 with ~12TB of capacity consisting of:

- 2 6TB disks
- 1 14TB disk (only uses 6TBs)
- All WD Reds
- QNAP T-651 (6 bays) - Firmware 5.0.1.2248 - 8GB Memory

The inconsistency in drive capacity came from a drive failure of one 6TB a while back and I wanted to future proof myself so bought the 14TB drive, and successfully restored the RAID. This has been find and running for years.

Now I'm at capacity.

I know I can buy 2 14TB drives and expand the RAID5 disks one-by one, but would prefer to only spend the money on the 2nd drives when capacity warrants.

Ideally I buy 1 14TB drive, migrate everything there, and use the previously-purchased 14TB drive to make a RAID1 configuration. Using the remaining 2 6TB disks as I please (out of scope for question).

Buying 2 14TB drives is of course the simplest but double the money.

My preferred choice is to "clone everything" to the new 14TB volume (as single), then add the existing 14TB drive and make it a raid1. I just don't know how to do this and keep my settings for apps, and network configurations.

An alternative is I backup or snapshot to the new 14TB drive, wipe the RAID5 (scary!), and restore from the backup.  I don't know how to do this either and would need high confidence on steps given the need to trust the backup.